# ¿Como valido que cuando venga un campo con valor 0 en una funcion no se muestre ese dato?

Tags: reactjs

Buen día tengo una funcion que llena un select

```
roomtype(){
        fetch("/api-rest/agency/rooms/"+this.state.value, {
            method : 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'text/plain',
                'Authorization': "Bearer admin"
            }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                let data = responseJson.data.map(rooms => {return {value:rooms.room_type_category, text:rooms.room_category_desc}});
                this.setState({
                    room : data,
                })
            })

            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

En esa funcion trae los datos pero quiero validar que cuando uno de los campos que trae llamado "view_contract" sea igual a "0" no se muestre ese dato y se muestren solo los que tengan "view_contract" = "1".

El select se llena de la siguiente forma

```
<select name="RoomType" id="IDRoomType" className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-8">
                                                    <option value="0">Select ...</option>
                                                    { this.state.room.map((room)=>
                                                        <option key={room.value} value={room.value}>{room.text}</option>)
                                                    }
                                            </select>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola. Creo que podrías usar una operación ternaria antes de imprimir las opciones. Por ejemplo: `this.state.room.map((room)=> return room.view_contract ? null : <option>...</option>)`

Comment: intente hacerlo de la manera que comentas y aunque no me marca errores tampoco funciona ya que el ternario representa los valores true y false y en este caso va a mostrar solo los campos con el valor de ese campo en 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes filtrar los resultados antes de recorrerlos con el map.

```
<select
name="RoomType"
id="IDRoomType"
className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-8"
>
<option value="0">Select ...</option>
{this.state.room.filter(room => room.view_contract).map(room => (
    <option key={room.value} value={room.value}>
    {room.text}
    </option>
))}
</select>
```

De todas maneras tienes que asegurarte de que el numero que te trae el API no sea un string.

En ese caso sea un string podrias cambiar la validacion en el filter:

```
filter(room => room.view_contract === "1")
```

O la validación que necesites.

Recuerda que tambien puedes filtrar la data antes de guardarla en el estado de la misma manera si es que no la necesitas

```
this.setState({
  room : data.filter(room => room.view_contract),
})
```